# How to detect IIS failure when load balancing

Tags: iis

I've recently set up Windows NLB Custering for a couple of iis servers to handle load balancing and failover in case of hardware failure.  However, if the iis instance on one of the servers has failed, the NLB still sees the server as active and attempts to send traffic to it, which then responds with an error back to the user.

Is there a way to interrogate the status of the iis service on the box prior to pushing traffic to it?

I've tried setting up the NLB to run only on port 80, but this still doesn't failover

Any thoughts how I can do this without spending any money???

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to set ARR load balance  is enough. ARR load balancer health test and live traffic test will check whether the resource servers every few seconds. If it detect unhealthy response, then it will mark the corrupted as unhealthy. Then all requests will be routed to other server.
https://blogs.iis.net/richma/application-request-routing-health-check-features

Comment: Can IIIS send out alerts when a server is marked as unhealthy.